# Designing a 2 bit magnitude comparator

Tags: comparator

As a foreword I would like to say that I am asking this question as part of a computer science course assignment, and any responses here might be referenced in my report. I am ideally looking for hints and tips to get me on the right track rather than straight up solutions.

What I am trying to get my head around is a 2 bit magnitude comparator circuit that takes in 2 sets of inputs. For example set A would contain a0 and a1, and set B would contain b0 and b1.
The only output I am interested in is A > B which means the sum of all inputs in set A is bigger than set B so a0 = 1 , a1 = 1, b0 = 1, b1 = 0 would overall output a 0 and so on.

I understand how a 1 bit comparator works :

[image]

this is the most basic circuit I came up with that takes in 2 inputs and gives out an output if A > B.

However, I have been stuck for several hours trying to increase the number of inputs. My initial plan was to somehow reuse the 1 bit comparator and reuse it 3 times but every time I end up with something that ends up with an overly complicated version of the initial 1 bit circuit where the 3 inputs actually only give out 1 output and so in the end you are going in a circle and comparing 2 numbers rather than 4.

Any advice an tips on this would be very appreciated.

Comment: Compare the "higher" inputs first. Only if they are equal, compare the "lower" inputs.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by higher and lower inputs, could you elaborate a little please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets examine what a comparator should do:

> If `A1` is greater than `B1` then output 1, otherwise continue.
>   If `A0` is greater than `B0` then output 1, otherwise output 0.

So now we can break this into parts.

> If `A1` is greater than `B1`

This one you already have.

\$X_1 = A_1 \overline{B_1}\$

> If `A0` is greater than `B0`

Second verse, same as the first.

\$X_0 = A_0 \overline{B_0}\$

> ... then output 1, otherwise continue. ...  then output 1, otherwise output 0.

Let's put up a truth table for this.

```
X1 X0  O
1  X   1
0  1   1
0  0   0
```

\$O = X_1 + X_0\$

So altogether we have:

\$O = A_1 \overline{B_1} + A_0 \overline{B_0}\$

And you're done.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me to picture the problem and get the solution.